# How to create a two column flexbox with an element that has a colspan of 2

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a structure like this:

```css
.main-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col1 {
  flex-basis: 66%
}

.col2 {
  flex-basis: 33%
}

.one-column {
  background-color: green;
}

.two-column {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-div'>
  <div class='col1'>
    <div class='one-column'>
      Some Text in Pos 1-1
    </div>
    <div class='one-column'>
      Some Text in Pos 1-2
    </div>
    <div class='two-column'>
      Some Text in Pos 1-3
    </div>
    <div class='one-column'>
      Some Text in Pos 1-4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col2'>
    <div class='one-column'>
      Some Text in Pos 2-1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Link to full structure on Codepen](https://codepen.io/j4ever/pen/zYamPKb)

The thing is that I need the div with the two-column class fill the 2 columns (col1 and col2)

How can I do that?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: use css grid, not flexbox

Comment: Are you stuck with that HTML or can you change it?

Comment: No I can't change the structure :(